# How to filter with choices | Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to filter this `item` with `category` but in this way it doesn't show the correct result in filtering. **Example:** when I searched by `Outwear` it didn't show any item(though I have this type of `items`).

As well as when I use `Q(category=query)` and searched by `S`/`SW`/`OW` it shows the correct result.

**models.py**

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Shirt'),
        ('SW', 'Sport wear'),
        ('OW', 'Outwear')
    )

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return qs.filter(Q(category__in=query))
        return qs
```